# Show that between any two real roots of the equation $e^x \cos{x}+1=0$, there is a root of the equation $e^x \sin{x}+1=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My steps are the following:

Suppose $f(a)=f(b)=0$
Since $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and continuous on $(a,b)$

By Rolle's Theorem $\exists c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$f'(c)=e^c(-\sin{c})+e^c \cos{c}=0$$

So what I found is $\sin{c}=\cos{c}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: First multiply by $e^{-x}$, then use Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: but why do we multiply by $e^{-x}$?

Comment: Because $\dfrac{d}{dx} (\cos(x) + e^{-x}) = -(\sin(x) + e^{-x})$.