# Prove that there exists at least one root of $g$ between any two roots of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Given that $$f(x)= 1 - e^x\sin(x)$$
$$g(x)= 1 + e^x\cos(x)$$

**Using Rolle's theorem**,  prove that there exists at least one root of $g$ between any two roots of $f$. Attempt so far:

$f'(x) = -e^x(\sin(x)+\cos(x))= f(x)-g(x)$

Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and differentiable, Rolle's theorem is applicable. Let $a$ and $b$ be any $2$ roots of $f$. Then by Rolle's theorem, there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c) =0$. Therefore,$$f'(c)=0=f(c)-g(c)$$ $$\implies f(c)=g(c)$$

That is where I got stuck and I don't know how to proceed. Am I on the right track? What else should I be doing? Am I at all on the right track?

Comment: You should consider $f_1(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$ and apply Rolle's theorem to $f_1$. See the answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118467/show-that-between-any-two-real-roots-of-the-equation-ex-cosx1-0-there-is?rq=1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785107/prove-that-between-any-two-roots-of-f-there-exists-at-least-one-root-of-g